# How to deal with onConflictStrategy.IGNORE in Android MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I have:

1. **Room Entity** `Book(id, name, code)`
2. Repository with and `AsyncTask` inner class that inserts a `Book` object
3. ViewModel that conveys Activity's requests to Repository
4. A `DAO` with follwing line of code:

   `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   long storeStream(Stream stream);`

The `DAO` returns -1 to the Repository's `AsyncTask` in case of any conflict which means that the object was not inserted. But how do I get this failure result (i.e, -1) in my `View`(Activity)?

Do I set a series of callback/interface that stretches from my `View`(Activity) to the `Repository` that lets me now the conflicts (**which is really inconvenient**)?

NOTE: OnChanged callback of the `LiveData` Observer in my View does not trigger in case of failure of insertion.

Comment: Your question is not about Room conflicts but MVVM architecture. Please rename the headline.

I recommend you to read more about MVVM to learn about activity -> viewModel -> activity interaction principles

Comment: can you please suggest a specific material?

Comment: You can read this article

`https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b`

Comment: I am struggling with a similar issue. Is there any chance you found an answer to your question by now?